# passing array parameters to smarty PHP template include

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, associative-array, server-side-includes

On a PHP site using the smarty template engine (or at least a close relative of smarty), I am calling a template include file ("header.html") which contains this code excerpt, along with other HTML omitted here for clarity:

```
<title>{$title|escape:"html"}</title>
{if isset($META) && $META}
    {foreach from=$META item=m}
        <meta name="{$m[0]}" content="{$m[1]}">
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

I currently have this line in the parent page template:

```
{include file="header.html" title="My WebSite Title Goes here"}
```

If I want to change this line to add two META tags into my HTML, what is the right syntax to define the array which the `header.html` template is looking for?

*Caveat: I'm unfamiliar with PHP, so I apologize if this is an obvious newbie question. Also, from some digging in the source code and from the comments below, I believe the site is using smarty for a template engine, although I can't be sure it's not a forked version.*

Comment: No offense meant, but this is one stupid templating system. Nothing like what its name suggests.

Comment: At first, it looks like Smarty, but the syntax is subtly not right...

Comment: None taken-- it's not my templating system. :-)

Comment: Charles - from poking around in the code, it does look like the site is using smarty, or at lesat a variant of smarty. what is subtly not right about the syntax above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:
in PHP:

```
$smarty->assign("myArray",array("some_key" => "some_value","key2" => "value2"));
```

in SMARTY:

```
{include file="header.html" title="your title" myParam=$myArray}
```

Comment: was hoping for a template-only solution, but I guess I can always use a {php} block around the code above.